# Android launchWhenResumed is not called when the app comes to foreground from background

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-lifecycle

In my fragment,

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        Log.e(TAG, "Inside on view created")

        lifecycleScope.launchWhenResumed {
            Log.e(TAG, "Inside lifecyclescope get data")
            viewModel.getData().collect {
              // ....
            
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        Log.e(TAG, "Inside on resume")
        super.onResume()
    }
```

Here are the log sequences in different scenarios -

1. When App opened freshly -

   Inside on view created

   Inside on resume

   Inside lifecyclescope get data
2. When coming back from a fragment to this fragment -

   Inside on view created

   Inside on resume

   Inside lifecyclescope get data

Now comes the problem...

3. When the app comes to foreground from the background -

   Inside on resume

As you see, I only see the `onResume()` log but I also expect the log `Inside lifecyclescope get data` to appear. Am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: When the app comes to foreground from the background - fragment/activity only call onResume method in foreground from the background process

Comment: `launchWhenResumed` is only scheduling one (potentially) delayed execution. Since your fragment is not undergoing `onViewCreated` again it doesn't schedule anything to launch during resume.

Comment: @Pawel so should I move my launchWhenResumed inside onResume?

Comment: Your logging is executed only once. Try putting log inside `collect`, it should log every time you receive new data from viewmodel.

Comment: @Deinlandel The log Inside lifecyclescope get data is executed when I come back from some fragment to this fragment but not from app background to foreground. Why is it?

Comment: @Ma2340 because your getData() flow apparently produces only one result. As it was already pointed out, "launchWhenResumed is only scheduling one (potentially) delayed execution". If you want to executes this every time on resume, just put this code in onResume(). If it was Room database flow, for example, it would produce new value every time table is modified, so using it in onViewCreated is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 6):

I believe what you are looking for is `Lifecycle.repeatOnLifecycle`

```
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        lifecycle.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.RESUMED) {
                // Do stuff
            }
        }
    }
```

More info:

- https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle
- https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/a-safer-way-to-collect-flows-from-android-uis-23080b1f8bda